# MySQL trigger keeps adding two rows for every update

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, triggers

I am trying to update a 'ticketHistory' table after every update of my 'tickets' table.  I have the following trigger set up to run whenever my 'tickets' table is updated (usually when a field is edited):

```
 TRIGGER `ticket_edit` AFTER UPDATE ON `tickets` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO ticketHistory
    (ticketId, action, originator, assigned, date)
VALUES 
    (NEW.ticketId, "Edited", NEW.userId, NEW.assigned, NEW.lastUpdated);
```

Whenever an update is done in my app, the field being edited is updated, as well as the 'lastUpdated' time.  I think because two fields are being updated, it is running the trigger twice, resulting in two identical rows being inserted into my 'ticketHistory' table.  I only want one row inserted.

Is there a way to limit it to just one row being inserted?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

All database inserts and updates are being done using CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord.

My model:

```
public function editTicket($ticket)
{
    $q = $this->db->where('ticketId', $ticket['ticketId']);
    $q = $this->db->update('tickets', $ticket);

    $results = $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function edit_ticket()
{
    $ticketId = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $description = str_replace("\n", "\r", $this->input->post('description'));

    $ticket = array(
        'ticketId'    => $ticketId,
        'headline'    => $this->input->post('headline'),
        'description' => $description,
        'priority'    => $this->input->post('priority'),
        'category'   => $this->input->post('category'),
        'lastUpdated' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())
    );

    $this->tickets->editTicket($ticket);
}
```

Comment: in your code not shown, when you update `tickets`, do it in one statement not two. this should clear things up in `ticketHistory`.

Comment: Well, to make matters more confusing, I'm using CodeIgniters ActiveRecord to make the update when I update 'ticket'.  Is that doing it in two statements?

Comment: Haha!  I know, but I don't have a choice

Comment: can you post the code around codeigniter AR perhaps one of the gurus can see the obvious

Comment: edited OP to show CodeIgniter code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as a solution, I modified my trigger as such:

```
TRIGGER `ticket_edit` AFTER UPDATE ON `tickets`
FOR EACH ROW 
IF NEW.headline <> OLD.headline || NEW.description <> OLD.description || NEW.priority <> OLD.priority
THEN
    INSERT INTO ticketHistory
        (ticketId, action, originator, assigned, date)
    VALUES 
        (NEW.ticketId, "Edited", NEW.userId, NEW.assigned, NEW.lastUpdated);
END IF
```

By adding the conditionals, I think it only activated the trigger once, resulting in only one row being inserted.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function editTicket($ticket)
{
    $q = $this->db->where('ticketId', $ticket['ticketId']);
    echo "I am here again<br/>";
    $q = $this->db->update('tickets', $ticket);

    $results = $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Comment: I posted a solution that caused it to only add one row, but thanks for the help!

Comment: just make sure you don't have some outer wrapper and you think you are calling it once. obviously i can't step thru it good luck !

Comment: and tickets.ticketId is explicitly set by you, and tickets.lastUpdated is **not** being set explicitly by you (???). If that is correct where AR sets the timestamp for you, this has to be a common trigger problem faced by people.

Comment: Actually, I didn't mean to copy and paste that part over.  I was just testing that to see if it made a difference.  The solution I used was edited to correct that.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: what I am wondering is how does the second update statement (to lastUpdated) come to happen. Is it done by CI AR automatically.

Comment: It is set in the controller, and then passed to the model in an array.

Comment: so you can isolate and verify that the update to `tickers` happens in two places then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that's adding 2 different rows, but you could just make a primary key field and your DBMS wouldn't allow the duplicate.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you are misreading the first sentence or two of his question